# Adapt layout to all screen resolution - Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to create a form which appears on a button click. This is the output:
[image]

As you can see the main problems are two:

1. The green button on the right instead of at the center of the form;
2. The white part at the bottom of the form, which becomes bigger depending on the resolution of the devices. I don't know why it appears.

This is the xml of the form:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
style="@style/MyDialog"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_form"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/dateSelect"
    android:layout_centerInParent="false"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_16sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_7sdp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
    android:text="OK"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/whiteTextColor"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_7sdp">

</Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/dateSelect"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/genderRadioGroup"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Inserisci l'età"
    android:textColor="#050505"
    android:theme="@style/Button2Style"/>

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:id="@+id/genderRadioGroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/maleRadioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_3sdp"
        android:text="Maschio" />


    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/femaleRadioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/maleRadioButton"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_1sdp"
        android:text="Femmina" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: you can use LayoutParam for setting height and width , Gravity programmatically    use https://github.com/intuit/sdp library and if use size-2 for better result.

Comment: Use constraints.. Better than Linear and Relative layouts

Comment: Remove   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" from dateSelectButton.

Comment: for a work around you can use this wonderful library and use its dimens to control the UI, will work for almost every device
https://github.com/intuit/sdp

Comment: Remove android:gravity="center" from Relative layout. Green button appears in center of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pls check the below code i am deleted the styles pls add it below code**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout      
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_form"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/dateSelect"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="OK"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dateSelect">

    </Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dateSelect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/genderRadioGroup"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="Inserisci l'età"
        android:textColor="#050505"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/genderRadioGroup" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/genderRadioGroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/maleRadioButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Maschio" />


        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/femaleRadioButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/maleRadioButton"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Femmina" />
    </RadioGroup>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you! I almost solved the problem, as you can see only a small white part remains: https://imgur.com/a/lKQXQXO Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: Nope, this is the style of the form: <shape `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid
        android:color="#00000000" />
    <stroke
        android:width="5dp"
        android:background="#00ffffff" />

    <corners android:radius="0dp" />
</shape>`

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <stroke
        android:width="5sp"
        android:color="#000000" />

    <corners android:radius="1sp" />
</shape>

Comment: its a drawable file and u can use as  """android:background="@drawable/filename"""" of that constraint layout..