# Is there a way to resize layouts with button click?

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I am developing an app for large screens (24 inch - 30 inch) and I need a way to make it easier for wheelchair users to use the app. The first idea I have is resize all activities to a percent (50%) and put layout to bottom left or right. But I dont know how it can be done and need help or a different solution for the problem.

What i want is with a button click resize activity layout to example below. orange color represents activity and black orange image is when activity size reduced to size.

[image: Activity layout is orange]

[image: Activity layout reduced to size]

Answer (score 0):

You can set other xml which have difference size which make you can design your UI depend what type device user used. There four type size = small, normal, large, and extra large (CMIIW). You can use this for reference

1. [Adapt layout to all screen resolution - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58854560/adapt-layout-to-all-screen-resolution-android)
2. https://youtu.be/th9YQ8nmhNg

Comment: Hi thanks  for the answer but i guess i couldnt express myself i want to make the activity layout reduce its height and width to a 10 inch tablet (1920*1080) from 30 inch (1920*1080).